# Extract a particular string from a file and output to another file using grep, awk, sed

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

I have a file and it contain the ff strings

```
2013-09-08 21:00:54 SMTP connection from [78.110.75.245]:5387 (TCP/IP connection count = 20)
2013-09-08 21:00:54 SMTP connection from [188.175.142.13]:34332 (TCP/IP connection count = 20)
2013-09-08 21:45:41 SMTP connection from [58.137.11.145]:51984 (TCP/IP connection count = 20)
2013-09-08 21:49:26 SMTP connection from [109.93.248.151]:22273 (TCP/IP connection count = 20)
2013-09-08 21:49:27 SMTP connection from [37.131.64.203]:7906 (TCP/IP connection count = 20)
```

What I want to do is extract the IP address only and save it to a file.

I started with this

```
sed '^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$' file > ips
```

But I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}' log.file > addresses
78.110.75.245
188.175.142.13
58.137.11.145
109.93.248.151
37.131.64.203
```

Answer (score 1):

In practice I would probably go with **[jasonwryan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18713250/1066031)** solution but to answer why your `sed` command doesn't work is because you are using [**extended regular expression**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) and even perl compliant regular expressions. To use ERE with `sed` you need to explicitly turn it on using `-r` with `GNU sed` or `-E` with BSD variants. However `sed` doesn't support PCRE but you can drop the use of non-capturing groups as it doesn't really help here anyway.

As you are just pattern matching `grep` is probably better then `sed`:

```
$ grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' file
78.110.75.245
188.175.142.13
58.137.11.145
109.93.248.151
37.131.64.203
```

Notice the anchors also need dropping, that is `^` and `$` as the pattern you want to match does not start at the beginning of the string or end at the end. `grep` also doesn't support extend regular expression by default so `-E` is used and `-o` prints only the matching part of the line not the whole line.

The final problem is you have just given `sed` and regular expression and a file. `sed` is not `grep` and won't just print out lines that match *(although of course it can, this just isn't how you do it)*. An approach would be to use the substitution command `s` and replace everything before the IP and everything after:

```
$ sed -r 's/.+[[]([^]]+).+/\1/' file
78.110.75.245
188.175.142.13
58.137.11.145
109.93.248.151
37.131.64.203
```

Regexplanation:

```
s    # sed substitute command 
/    # the delimiter marking the start of the regexp
.+   # one or more of any character
[    # start a character class
[    # character class contains a single opening square bracket 
]    # close character class (needed so single [ isn't treated as unclosed)
(    # start capture group
[    # start character class
^]+  # one or more character not an ]
]    # end character class
)    # end capture group 
.+   # one or more of any character
/    # the delimiter marking the end of the regexp and start of replacement
\1   # the first capture group
/    # the delimiter marking the end of the replacement
```

[**Here**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) is a comparison of different regular expression flavours.

Answer (score 0):

You could match the content between the brackets `[]` with `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' log.file
```